# Finding solutions to a pair of linear inequalities

Tags: inequality

I am faced with this question:

> Which $x$ satisfies both $|x−3|  < 2$ and  $|x−5|  < 1$ ?

This is what I have figured out:

> $1< x<5$    and    $4 < x<6$

Now I am not sure of what to do, for the first range of numbers $4$ satisfies it, and for the second $5$ satisfies it. I need to find one number that satisfies both.

Would the answer be anything greater than $4$ but less than $5$? For example: $4.2$.

Comment: If $x$ does not need to be an integer, then you have given the answer above: any $x$ between 4 and 5 will do.

Comment: Also, you recognize that $X$ is not the same as $x$.  You recognize this in English (I hope), why not in math?

Answer (score 2):

You find a number that satisfies $1 \lt x \lt 5$ and   $4 \lt x \lt 6$. The intersection is $4 \lt x \lt 5$, any number in that range will work.